# ruby redis client scan not working using 3.0.7

Tags: ruby, redis

I have upgraded my ruby redis client to 3.0.7.
Then this method worked on my localhost

```
[5] pry(main)> $redis.scan(0, :match => "restrict*")
[
    [0] "5",
    [1] [
        [0] "restrict_3",
        [1] "restrict_2"
    ]
]
```

but on my remote server it fails (like it fails on localhost before the upgrade)

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > $redis.scan(0, :match => "question*")
Redis::CommandError: ERR unknown command 'scan'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@my_app/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:97:in `call'
```

any ideas why?

Edit:
here is the output of `bundle show redis`

```
localhost
/Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@my_app/gems/redis-3.0.7
remote
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@app/gems/redis-3.0.7
```

Edit:
The issue was resolved. the redis (server , not the ruby client) was 2.6, It should be higher.

Comment: What about `$redis.get("some_key")`, does this work in the *remote* server? Also can you do a `$ bundle show redis-rb` in your *local* machine and paste the output?

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I don't want to use that since I've heard there is a real preformance issue using this method.

Comment: @Agis I don't want to use the `keys` method + updated the question with the output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49044/discussion-between-webqube-and-agis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that the remote server was running Redis server v2.6.

[`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) was added in 2.8 though.